# Encrypt conversations

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to develop an application that encrypt all my conversations that I have. MSN conversations, Google Talk conversations, or any other.

How can I develop an application like that? What is the best architecture?

What can I use to achieve this... What encryption protocol?

Thanks.

P.S.: I want to use Java.

Comment: Where/how would the application be used? Would all the parties involved have access to a certificate authority?

Comment: No, you probably do not want to do that.  Kudos for asking how, but the simple answer is unless you want to show up in Schneier's Doghouse, you shouldn't be developing any crypto application of any sort, and should leave it to the professionals, i.e. people who are fanatical about cryptography.

Comment: I want to use an application that "cathes" all conversations and encrypt them. Is that possible? How can I capture all conversations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Off-the-Record Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) might be the encryption protocol you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Like [Telcontar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606494/encrypt-conversations/1606626#1606626): Build upon an existing open source software.

Try [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im) + the [OTR plugin](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) (Off The Record encryption) as a basis. With this combination you have all necessary stuff and you can include a source for all public keys.

A secured central Website for your contacts could be referenced, too. So every user could just open this webpage from Pidgin and receive the matching key. If this website is secured by a well known authority SSL cert, it's perfect.

Pidgin supports Jabber, Google Talk, AIM, Yahoo, ICQ, MSN, whatever and is available for all well-known platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible as you think of it. If you are encrypting your message the client of your peer must be able to decrypt it. So, both of us need your client.

Maybe you can implement a client that encrypt conversations only when both peers are prepared for that. I think aMSN source code is available and is possible that all you need to create is a plugin.

For encrypting messages fast, the best option is a block encryption algorithm, as AES. First, you need to share a key, e.g. with a public key encryption as RSA.

Keep us in touch about your success ;)

Comment: That's what I want to do.

Both clients must install my application to encrypt all conversations.

My app must access to all conversations that come in, or goes out and desencrypt or encrypt them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find an java opensource application which can use MSN and Jabber (GTalk uses it) protocols and adapt it